# Selecting/renaming/simplifying MultiIndex dataframes

Tags: pandas

After some groupby and pivot operations my resulting dataframe ends up with multilevel column and index values.

Can someone please give some example on how to manipulate these multi-value columns?

For example, here are what the columns now look like:

```
>>> result.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'min', u'median', u'mean', u'max', u'std', u'count'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
           names=[None, u'Nums'])
```

Is there a way rename the columns to the combined strings of the levels like: “1-min”, “3-median”.

Would it be better to keep the MultiIndex for the functionality, a just rename the labels?
I would like to find a way to select the columns by the combinations of the levels (“1-min”, “3-median”).

Also, right now when I export the dataframe to a csv file, I have the MultiIndex column values in two rows (row 1- “min” row 2- “1”) and would like to have them combined in one.

The question is a bit broad but I wanted to see what options/functions were there to work with this kind of result.

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: `results[[(1, 'min'), (3, 'median')]]` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the level values of the MultiIndex and use array operations to add them together.

```
result.columns.get_level_values(1).astype(str) + '-' + result.columns.get_level_values(0)

Index(['1-min', '2-min', '3-min', '4-min', '5-min', '1-median', '2-median',
       '3-median', '4-median', '5-median', '1-mean', '2-mean', '3-mean',
       '4-mean', '5-mean', '1-max', '2-max', '3-max', '4-max', '5-max',
       '1-std', '2-std', '3-std', '4-std', '5-std', '1-count', '2-count',
       '3-count', '4-count', '5-count'],
      dtype='object')
```